# On opening Product Single page gave error from Admin in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, admin, reindex

I have 60 million Products in my Magento Store.
In my Magento 2 Admin When i go to admin panel and click on to view a product it gives me an error .

Class StripeIntegration\Payments\Model\Adminhtml\Source\BillingInterval does not exist but i didn't install any Stripe Plugin.

[image]

Any help is Appriciated.

Comment: Please share composer.json file code this module :- **StripeIntegration\Payments**

Comment: @MohitPatel Added Please Check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Please check**
`SELECT * FROM eav_attribute WHERE eav_attribute.attribute_code LIKE '%stripe%'`

and delete those entries from db stripe was install before but their attribute code is still in db that is called on product view from admin panel

Comment: Thanks for your response it solve my problem.
will you please help me with this question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/328216/indexerreindex-not-running-in-magento-2?noredirect=1#comment468583_328216

Comment: I'm glad it helps sure I will answer that question as well