# indexer:reindex not running in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, frontend, reindex, indexing

I have 60 million product in my Magento 2 Store.

On running sudo php bin/magento indexer:reindex it will run successfull for only 2 the don't know why it doesn't show any error.

[image]

[image]

Any it will not validate further so my product are not visible on froentend

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Probably 60m products need time to reindex. Open another terminal tab and check the indexers status by running php bin/magento indexer:status

Comment: @Nikolas Thanks for your response.
catalog_category_product  | Category Products  | Processing  it will show processing from last 1.5 days any idea about when it will complete or any error which will log.

Comment: magento version ???

Comment: @RkRathod Magento version = 2.3.5-p1

Comment: can you add screen shot of bin/magento indexer:status

Comment: @YasirLatif added please check.

Comment: can you run this on console as well

Comment: @YasirLatif that screenshot is attached ( 1st screenshot )

Answer (score 0):

go to your root Magento directory run the below commands
to reset index for category products

```
php bin/magento indexer:reset catalog_category_product
```

Comment: after that run indexer again

Comment: Thanks for your response i have tried that but still it will show in processing from around 15 min.

Answer (score 0):

can you reindex one by one instead of reindexing all at a time

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_category_product 
php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_product_category
```

Comment: Thanks for your response I have done that also but it is still in working from around 3 days.